# Mirror object rotated

Tags: mirror

Cannot apply the roof to opposite side with mirror modifier
Its rotated somehow , Is there a way to reset it?

[image]

Comment: Try applying the rotation to your object CTRL + A > Rotation.

Comment: read: [Why is it important to apply transformation to an objects data?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data)

Answer (score 1):

Apply the rotation to your object <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> *> Rotation.*

Comment: a tad brief, but I voted "looks OK."